# How to have a webview and a relative layout in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I have a linear layout, and inside that I have a webview and a relative layout. I want the webview to take up all the free space and let the relative layout keep it's height wrapped on the content.

I tried multiple ways but I still couldn't get it working properly.

Could someone explain to me how I could make the webview take up all the free space and keep my relative layout at the bottom with it's content wrapped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/titlebar_top">

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/redarrowright"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/imgArticlePrevious" android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imgArticleRight"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/redarrowleft"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgArticlePrevious"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
        android:id= "@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Le soleisl sssssssssssssssss"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="2">
</TextView>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCategory" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Info"
        android:textColor="@color/red">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="|">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtDate" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="26/03/2011"
        android:textColor="@color/gray">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>


<WebView android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout_weight="90" />

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/articlebanner"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="10">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imgComment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/commenticon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </ImageButton>

    <Button android:id="@+id/txtCommentCount"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/commentbackground"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:text="4" android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgComment">
    </Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/imgShare" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/buttonshare"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sharebtnicon"
        android:drawablePadding="2dip" android:text="Partagez"
        android:textColor="@color/white" android:textStyle="bold">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Webview - Takes up all the space remaining space between other widgets located at the top and bottom

Comment: can you post some sample code of your attempts?

Comment: `android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout_weight="90"` <-- that doesn't make sense. You have to set the axis that you want to grow or shrink according to a weight to 0px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/titlebar_top">

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/redarrowright"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/imgArticlePrevious" android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imgArticleRight"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/redarrowleft"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgArticlePrevious"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
        android:id= "@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="2">
</TextView>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCategory" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Info"
        android:textColor="@color/red">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="|">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtDate" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="26/03/2011"
        android:textColor="@color/gray">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sharebar" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sharebar"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/articlebanner"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imgComment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/commenticon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </ImageButton>

    <Button android:id="@+id/txtCommentCount"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/commentbackground"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:text="4" android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgComment">
    </Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/imgShare" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/buttonshare"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sharebtnicon"
        android:drawablePadding="2dip" android:text="Partagez"
        android:textColor="@color/white" android:textStyle="bold">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Solved, I put it in another relative layout, aligned the bar at the bottom and set the webview above it. Worked :)